# Angular where to store token or LoggedIn boolean if AuthGuard tries to reach it from server side?

Tags: angular, express, local-storage, server-side-rendering

I have `Auth.guard.ts` which is calling for token in `localStorage`, if it IS and is not expired it stays in that route.

The problem is that when your refresh the page there is Server but not browser for a little and it shows Log In page for like 1 second, when the person itself was in dashboard page.

How to store token/loggedIn boolean so it would always be reached - even when there is no browser ?

Comment: What do you mean with "there is no browser"? You mean there's no internet connection?

Comment: I mean that when you use Angular SSR, and You refresh the page , for a little like 500ms browser isnt loaded yet and there is only server (With server side rendering) functions starts to call on server and for these 500ms user sees Login page instead of Dashboard because there is no localStorage in server and Auth.Guard just routes to Login Page and when the browser loads up, it goes to Dashboard page.